# How to assign a UserForm to a Class (Types)?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a code that will be executed against all userforms in my workbook. So I wanted to create a Class. However, I'm stuck at this point.

The class name is `clsCmdUsrFormsE`

Variable declaration within the class:

```
Public WithEvents EndUserforms As UserForm
```

Objects assignation code:

```
Dim UserFormsAll() As New clsCmdUsrFormsE

Sub Cmd_UsrF(Optional var1 As Boolean = False)
    Dim iCmdUsrFrm As Integer, UsrForm As Object
    iCmdUsrFrm = 0
    For Each UsrForm In WBK0001.VBProject.VBComponents
        If UsrForm.Type = 3 Then
            iCmdUsrFrm = iCmdUsrFrm + 1
            ReDim Preserve UserFormsAll(1 To iCmdUsrFrm)
            Set UserFormsAll(iCmdUsrFrm).EndUserforms = UsrForm
        End If
    Next UsrForm
End Sub
```

& thew intent is to call `Cmd_UsrF` using a simple `call`

```
Sub Test()
    Call Cmd_UsrF
End Sub
```

The problem I'm having is that it seems the Userform as Object is not compatible with the Class.
I've tried as well with

```
Public WithEvents EndUserforms As msforms.UserForm
```

But all I get is

```
Run-time error '13': Type mismatch
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are tying to store `VBComponent` in `MsForm` and hence a type mismatch

[image]

Is this what you are trying?

```
Dim UserFormsAll() As New clsCmdUsrFormsE

Sub Cmd_UsrF(Optional var1 As Boolean = False)
    Dim iCmdUsrFrm As Integer, UsrForm As Object
    Dim frmname As String
    
    iCmdUsrFrm = 0
    
    For Each UsrForm In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        If UsrForm.Type = 3 Then
            iCmdUsrFrm = iCmdUsrFrm + 1
            ReDim Preserve UserFormsAll(1 To iCmdUsrFrm)

            '~~> Get the Name of the form
            frmname = UsrForm.Name
            
            '~~> Load the form
            Set UserFormsAll(iCmdUsrFrm).EndUserforms = UserForms.Add(frmname)
            
        End If
    Next UsrForm
End Sub
```

In Class Module

```
Public WithEvents EndUserforms As MSForms.UserForm
```

**Note:**

You can also bypass the variable `frmname` and directly use

```
Set UserFormsAll(iCmdUsrFrm).EndUserforms = UserForms.Add(UsrForm.Name)
```

Comment: Thanks, Siddharth. So I guess method Userform.Add is the correct way to convert variables into real objects for Userforms, right? Thanks!!!

Comment: Just a question. Wouldn't UserForms.Add "open" or "load" the userforms? I mean, would that execute the UserForm_Initialize procedures of each one of them?

Comment: Wish it was as simple as `Set frm = UserForms(i)`. AFAIK, you have to load up the form to store it and yes that will execute the `UserForm_Initialize` procedure. One can get away from it by using a public boolean variable which is set to true just before `Set UserFormsAll(iCmdUsrFrm).EndUserforms = UserForms.Add(UsrForm.Name)` and to false right after it. In the  `UserForm_Initialize` event you can check if the variable is true or not and simply prevent running of `_Initialize`